# Parabola and the corresponding point on the directrix

Tags: geometry, linear-algebra

Suppose we have the equation of the parabola `(y = x^2)`. See the figure below:

[image]

suppose we have a point `P` on this parabola, where `P=(-2,4)`. We know that the distance between any point on parabola (e.g. `P`) and the focus is equal to the distance
between the point `P` and the directrix. 
My question is, What the corresponding point (e.g. `P'`) of `P` on the directrix of the parabola, where the `distance between the focus and P = distance between P and P'`?  What is the equation which takes a point on the parabola and return the corresponding point on the directrix

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics. Please use http://math.stackexchange.com/ for this kind of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since focus and directrix have equal distance from *any* point on the parabola, they in particular have equal distance from the origin (0,0). You may assume that distance fo be d, so the focus would be at (0,d) and the directrix would be the line y=-d.

For any other point on the parabola, the squared distance to the line is
(y+d)<sup>2</sup> =
(x<sup>2</sup>+d)<sup>2</sup> =
x<sup>4</sup> + 2dx<sup>2</sup> + d<sup>2</sup>
and the squared distance to the focus is
x<sup>2</sup> + (y-d)<sup>2</sup> = x<sup>2</sup> + (x<sup>2</sup>-d)<sup>2</sup> = x<sup>2</sup> + x<sup>4</sup> - 2dx<sup>2</sup> + d<sup>2</sup>

These two expressions should be equal, so their difference should be zero:
(x<sup>4</sup> + 2dx<sup>2</sup> + d<sup>2</sup>) -
(x<sup>2</sup> + x<sup>4</sup> - 2dx<sup>2</sup> + d<sup>2</sup>) =
(4d-1)x<sup>2</sup>
From this you can read d=1/4. So your directrix is y=-1/4 and your focus is (0,1/4).

The point on the directrix which corresponds to a point on the parabola is simply its orthogonal projection. So if you have P=(x,y)=(x,x<sup>2</sup>) on the parabola, then you get P'=(x,-d)=P(x,-1/4).